# Classification column is removed after using dummyVars in caret package - R

Tags: r, r-caret

I am playing around with the caret package and came upon this question.

I am using `dummyVars` to split my categorical columns into separate dummy variables. It seems that `dummyVars` code removes the classification column in the input data set. For example:

```
library(earth)
data(etitanic)
dummies <- dummyVars(survived ~ ., data = etitanic, levelsOnly = FALSE)
et<-as.data.frame(predict(dummies, newdata = etitanic))
names(et)

[1] "pclass.1st" "pclass.2nd" "pclass.3rd" "sex.female" "sex.male"   "age"       
[7] "sibsp"      "parch"
```

So when I try to split the data, I get an error.

```
train = createDataPartition(et$survived, p=.75, list=FALSE)

Error in createDataPartition(et$survived, p = 0.75, list = FALSE) : 
  y must have at least 2 data points
```

Could anyone let me know if this is the expected behavior of caret's dummyVars. I can easily add in the survived column into the data set using say,

```
et$survived<-etitanic$survived
```

and then train a model. But I presume that there must be a better way or else the caret package would not remove the classification column. Am I missing something here? Could someone throw more light on this please?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know there is no way to keep the classification column in (or at least not as a factor; and that is because the output is a matrix and therefore it is always numeric). This is because the reason of the `dummyVars` function is to create dummy variables for the factor predictor variables. It is also designed to provide an alternative to the base R function `model.matrix` which offers more choices (`model.matrix` also does not keep the classification column).

Also, and maybe more importantly, functions that require the classification column to be of factor class and only of factor class offer either a way to provide the factor as a separate argument (like the `svm` function from the `e1071` package) or specifically require it as a separate argument (like the `knn` function from the `FNN` package). In both cases you do not need to have the factor in your data.frame. You just need to provide it as a separate vector in the function you want to use.

However, there is an alternative for the cases where you do not need the classification column to be of factor type in which case you can simply do:

```
library(earth)
data(etitanic)
etitanic2 <- etitanic
#convert the classification colunn to numeric
etitanic2$survived <- as.numeric(etitanic2$survived)
#use formula without specifying the response variable
dummies <- dummyVars( ~ ., data = etitanic, levelsOnly = FALSE)
et<-as.data.frame(predict(dummies, newdata = etitanic))
names(et)

> names(et)
[1] "pclass.1st" "pclass.2nd" "pclass.3rd" "survived"   "sex.female" "sex.male"   "age"       
[8] "sibsp"      "parch"
```

By converting the classification column into numeric and by not specifying a response variable in the formula, the `survived` column is kept in the output data.frame but as of numeric class.